# Getting the wrong Facebook Id in the AuthData Parse.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I facing a problem when trying to get Facebook friends list.
When user login Parse restore on the user AuthData a wrong (temporary) Facebook id, and than when I'm trying to pull the friends list I can't get it since the Facebook id is not the "real" Facebook id.

I'm getting all right permissions from Facebook at login time and can login my app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting an App Scoped ID, see **App-scoped User IDs** changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

It is not a temporary one, it will stay the same for every User in one App. It is just not the "real" one.

If you don´t get the friends (with `/me/friends`, i guess), it´s probably because you only get the friends who also use your App. This is also explained in the changelog:

> **App Friends:** The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that
>   person's friends who are also using your app.